# Dynamic header (csvsimple-l3 and tabularray packages)

Tags: tabularray, csvsimple-13

The input CSV file has a variable number of columns. The data is added to the second row in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th columns.
The input SCV file can have 3 or 4 columns, so the data above will be spread over a different number of columns, which is a variable that changes in the header according to the input CSV file.

It is necessary to define a dynamic header that will match the input CSV data.

I have created an example of Latex code, where everything is adapted to the input CSV file except the dynamic header. My attempt generated an error that I could not fix.

My Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{file3.csv}
 a,b,c
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file4.csv}
a,b,c,d
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GenerateHeader}{m}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1} { & }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff  

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\InputCSV}[1]{%
\readdef{#1}\filedata%
\csvreader[%
no head,
tabularray={colspec={X[1,c,m]
*{\ncols}{X[1,c,m]} X[1,c,m]X[1,c,m]},
hlines,vlines,
width=\textwidth,
colsep=2.5pt,
rowsep=4.5pt,
row{1-2}={c,m,fg=black,bg=black!10,font=\bfseries\small},
cell{1}{1}={r=2}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries,bg=black!10},
cell{1}{2}={c=\ncols}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries,bg=black!10},
cell{1}{\ncols+2}={c=2}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries,bg=black!10},
expand=\expanded,
},
table head=Sample&Span over 3 or 4 columns 
%&&&
\expanded{\GenerateHeader{\ncols}}
Last& \\
]{#1}
{}{%
\ifnumequal{\ncols}{4}{%
       Name  &\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcoliv&Result & Erros 
                            }{%
\ifnumequal{\ncols}{3}{%
       Name  &\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&Result & Erros
                            }{}%                              
                            }
  }%
}

\InputCSV{file3.csv}

\bigskip

The file consists of \ncols{} columns. 

\end{document}
```

This is how the output table should look depending on the input SCV file.

[image]

[image]

If anyone has an idea of how to solve this problem and can provide an example, that would be very helpful.
It is important that the csvsimple-l3 and tabularray packages are used in the given example.